# Как настроить связь между двумя полями в GUI

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qlineedit, выпадающий-список

Нужно настроить связь между двумя полями. Например, если содержимое поля `type != fixedValue`, то скрывать поле value, или делать его неактивным.

Как это реализовать?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QDoubleValidator
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QHBoxLayout, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout, QFormLayout, QWidget


class BlockPU(QWidget):
    def __init__( self):
    super().__init__()

    self.block_pU_form = QFormLayout()
    self.setLayout(self.block_pU_form)
    self.block_pU_form.setSpacing(70)
    self.block_pU_form.setVerticalSpacing(20)

    tophbox = QHBoxLayout()
    tophbox.addWidget(QLabel("Pressure (m2/c2)"))
    tophbox.addWidget(QLabel("Velocity (m/c)"))
    self.block_pU_form.addRow("Patch", tophbox)

    for row in range(1, 7):
        patch_hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        patch_hbox.setSpacing(50)

        tv_vbox =QVBoxLayout()
        tv_vbox.setSpacing(2)
        tv_vbox.addWidget(QLabel("type"))
        tv_vbox.addWidget(QLabel("value"))
        patch_hbox.addLayout(tv_vbox)

        p_tv_vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        p_tv_vbox.setSpacing(2)
        ptype = QComboBox()
        ptype.addItems(["empty", "fixedValue", "noSlip"])
        pvalue = QLineEdit()
        pvalue.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(-999999, 999999, 50))

        p_tv_vbox.addWidget(ptype)
        p_tv_vbox.addWidget(pvalue)
        patch_hbox.addLayout(p_tv_vbox)


        U_tv_vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        U_tv_vbox.setSpacing(2)
        Utype = QComboBox()
        Utype.addItems(["zeroGradient", "fixedValue"])
        Uvalue = QHBoxLayout()
        xU = QLineEdit()
        yU = QLineEdit()
        zU = QLineEdit()
        xU.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(-999999, 999999, 50))
        yU.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(-999999, 999999, 50))
        zU.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(-999999, 999999, 50))
        Uvalue.addWidget(xU)
        Uvalue.addWidget(yU)
        Uvalue.addWidget(zU)

        U_tv_vbox.addWidget(Utype)
        U_tv_vbox.addLayout(Uvalue)
        patch_hbox.addLayout(U_tv_vbox)

        self.block_pU_form.addRow(QLabel(""), patch_hbox)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = BlockPU()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QDoubleValidator
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QHBoxLayout, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout, QFormLayout, QWidget


class BlockPU(QWidget):
    def __init__( self):
        super().__init__()

        self.block_pU_form = QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.block_pU_form)
        self.block_pU_form.setSpacing(70)
        self.block_pU_form.setVerticalSpacing(20)

        tophbox = QHBoxLayout()
        tophbox.addWidget(QLabel("Pressure (m2/c2)"))
        tophbox.addWidget(QLabel("Velocity (m/c)"))
        self.block_pU_form.addRow("Patch", tophbox)

        for row in range(1, 7):
            patch_hbox = QHBoxLayout()
            patch_hbox.setSpacing(50)

            tv_vbox =QVBoxLayout()
            tv_vbox.setSpacing(2)
            tv_vbox.addWidget(QLabel("type"))
            tv_vbox.addWidget(QLabel("value"))
            patch_hbox.addLayout(tv_vbox)

            p_tv_vbox = QVBoxLayout()
            p_tv_vbox.setSpacing(2)
            ptype = QComboBox()
            ptype.addItems(["empty", "fixedValue", "noSlip"])

            pvalue = QLineEdit()
            pvalue.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(-999999, 999999, 50))

            ptype.currentTextChanged.connect(                                             # +++
                lambda text, cb=ptype, le=pvalue: self.on_combobox_func(text, cb, le))    # +++

            p_tv_vbox.addWidget(ptype)
            p_tv_vbox.addWidget(pvalue)
            patch_hbox.addLayout(p_tv_vbox)


            U_tv_vbox = QVBoxLayout()
            U_tv_vbox.setSpacing(2)
            Utype = QComboBox()
            Utype.addItems(["zeroGradient", "fixedValue"])
            Uvalue = QHBoxLayout()
            xU = QLineEdit()
            yU = QLineEdit()
            zU = QLineEdit()
            xU.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(-999999, 999999, 50))
            yU.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(-999999, 999999, 50))
            zU.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(-999999, 999999, 50))
            Uvalue.addWidget(xU)
            Uvalue.addWidget(yU)
            Uvalue.addWidget(zU)

            U_tv_vbox.addWidget(Utype)
            U_tv_vbox.addLayout(Uvalue)
            patch_hbox.addLayout(U_tv_vbox)

            self.block_pU_form.addRow(QLabel(""), patch_hbox)
            self.show()

    def on_combobox_func(self, text, cb, le):                               # +++
        #print(text, cb, le)
        if text == 'fixedValue':
            le.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            le.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = BlockPU()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Работает, спасибо)

Comment: @user12589893 пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

После блока кода:

```
ptype = QComboBox()
ptype.addItems(["empty", "fixedValue", "noSlip"])
pvalue = QLineEdit()
pvalue.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(-999999, 999999, 50))
```

Добавьте вот эти пару строк:

```
# Сигнал о выборе другого значения в комбобоксе
ptype.currentTextChanged.connect(lambda text, edt=pvalue: edt.setEnabled( text == "fixedValue"))

# Установим изначальную доступность pvalue
pvalue.setEnabled(ptype.currentText() == "fixedValue")
```

Comment: Почему то это работает только для последней строки, в предыдущих строках поле value не активно при любом выборе type

Comment: @user12589893 подправил

Comment: Теперь я полем value последней строки могу упрявлять из полей type предыдущих строк, при этом value у ни все также не активно)))

Comment: @user12589893 да, у вас же там цикл. Сейчас подправим

Comment: Работает, спасибо)

Comment: @user12589893 это хорошо, но галочку верните S. Nick - он дал верный ответ первым ) Меня можно отблагодарить просто нажав стрелочку вверх )

Comment: оу, я думала можно ставить несколько галочек))